# *ngIf and translate pipe don't work on first render in Ionic Modal

Tags: angular, ionic5

*ngIf directives aren't rendering the proper children and the translate pipe returns nothing the first time I display a modal in Ionic 5.

The *first* time my modal renders it places `<!-- container -->` where each `*ngIf` output should be in the HTML. If I close the modal and reopen it each `*ngIf` renders a `<!-- bindings={ ... } -->` comment and the expected output of the `*ngIf`.

Psuedocode below:

my.page.html

```html
...
<button (click)="displayModal()">Show Modal</button>
...
```

my.page.ts

```js
displayModal() {
  this.modalCtrl
    .create({
      component: MyModalComponent,
      componentProps: { data: 'foo' }
    })
    .then((m) => m.present());
}
```

my.modal.html

```html
<ion-modal-view>
  <div #mainDiv>
    <div *ngIf="data === 'foo'">
      Hello, World!
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      {{ 'HELLO.WORLD' | translate }}
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-modal-view>
```

The output of the above modal HTML looks like:

```
...
<ion-modal-view>
  <div #mainDiv>
    <!-- container -->
    <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
  </div>
</ion-modal-view>
...
```

I have tried importing `my.modal.module.ts` in `my.page.module.ts` and `app.module.ts` with no luck.

Comment: Is your data in the real code coming from some async function?

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7 In my real code it is 2 enums. It is triggered from a click handler in the page's HTML.